# Delete first four rows in Excel with Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, row

I have a powershell script that opens an excel file, re-assigns a blank password, and then saves the file.  I want to add a task to the script to remove the first 4 rows of the excel file before saving it.

Answer (score 10):

You can't use OleDB for deleting data from Excel document. As per [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934) docmentation:

> Although the Jet OLE DB Provider allows you to insert and update
>   records in an Excel workbook, it does not allow DELETE operation

What you can do is use Exel's COM interface to delete rows. Remember to [release COM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730962.aspx) object too. Like so,

```
$file = c:\temp\MyExcelFile.xls
# Star Excel, hide window
$excel = new-object -com Excel.Application -Property @{Visible = $false} 
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($file) # Open the file
$sheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item(1) # Activate the first worksheet
[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the first row

$workbook.Close($true) # Close workbook and save changes
$excel.quit() # Quit Excel
[Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) # Release COM
```

Comment: Hi, Perfect, TY!  Would you happen to know how to use a dynamic file name in the same script...ends with "mmddyyyy"?

Comment: You should post the part about dynamic file name as a question of its own. Provide more info about how the name is going to change and what should one do to the file(s) after removing the 1st row.